# It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, google-fabric

I have enabled the project settings of the project and target and set Debug Information Format for both Debug and Release to DWARF with dSYM File.
I have enabled the Bitcode to NO.

But I am getting the error "**we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below**".

I have followed the below steps to generate dSYMs file.

```
1.  Go to the Window Menu -> Organizer in Xcode.

2.  Select the right version of build and click on the button "Download Debug Symbols" on the right panel

3.  Right Click on right version of build and select show in Finder.

4.  Select an .xcarchieve file then right click on that and click on Show Package contents

5.  Then Go to *dSYMs folder* and select .dSYM file and compress that file.

6.  Now Final Step is to upload compressed file on fabric.
```

My question is when i add the new DSYM file into the fabric, will it remove the existing crashes logs??

Comment: “when i add the new DSYM file into the fabric, will it remove the existing crashes logs?” - No, it won’t. Previously symbolicated crashes with other DSYMs will still be there. And crashes associated the particular DSYM that you just uploaded will also still be there, except they’ll now be symbolicated.

Comment: By the way, that process you outline above is if you need to upload a DSYM for the current version, but if you’re trying to upload DSYMs for previous App Store uploads, you can retrieve the DSYMs for these old versions on the App Store Connect as outlined earlier in that link that Anbu shared with you (tho it’s now “App Store Connect”, not “iTunes Connect”). But, again, all the old Fabric crashes should all still be there, but the ones associated with that version will just be symbolicated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Arun because every time you recompile your project after adding a line of code, the dSYM changes because the address of your lines of the code in resulting binary is not the same that's the reason remove the existing crashes logs. You can look below link https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script

Answer (score 0):

@Arun, Make sure you are uploading the correct dSYM (UUID of missing dSYM matches with uploading dSYM). If fabric do not process these dSYM then reach out to us at support@fabric.io and we can look into this further.